# Using QtConcurrent::MappedReduce in a class

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently learning `QtConncurrenct` for multi threaded applications. So for testing purposes I decided to implement a simple program that sums integers in a list, here is the code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <functional>

class intObj{
    int m_value;
public:
    intObj(int val = 0):m_value(val){}

    int val() const {return m_value;}

};

static intObj mapFunction(const intObj &num){
    return intObj(num.val());
}

static void reduceFunction(intObj &sum, const intObj &term){
    int x = sum.val();
    int y = term.val();
    sum = intObj(x+y);
}


class myTest{
    public:
    int getSum(QList<intObj> numbers);

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QList<intObj> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++){
        n.append(intObj(i));
    }

    myTest m;
    int sum = m.getSum(n);
    return a.exec();
}


int myTest::getSum(QList<intObj> numbers){
    auto sum = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(numbers,mapFunction,reduceFunction);
    return sum.result().val();
}
```

This program now runs correctly but the map and reduce functions are outside the class. How can I modify this program such that map and reduce functions are in class intObj?

I would really appreciate a working example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't edit your question by removing the original code... If you want to add extra information, add it after the original code - It's hard for future readers to understand the question and the answers if the question changed drastically.

Comment: Ok, I remeber that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass pointer to method to `mappedReduced` like that.

- If you don't need the object inside the MapFunction and ReduceFunction, you should make the two functions `static`:

```
static int mappedFunction(const int num){
    return num;
}

static void reduce(int &sum, const int term){
    sum += term;
}
```

- If you need to use the object, you could use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (see [*using bound function arguments*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentmap.html#using-bound-function-arguments)):

```
auto sum = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(numbers,
    std::bind(&myTest::mappedFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1),
    std::bind(&myTest::reduce, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));

// Or lambda if Qt support them:
auto sum = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(numbers, 
    [this] (int num) { mappedFunction(num); },
    [this] (int &sum, int num) { reduce(sum, num); });
```

You could also use [Function Objects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentmap.html#using-function-objects) and store a reference to your current `myTest` instance.

Comment: In modern C++ the idiom is to use lambda. `std::bind` is unnecessary when you have lambdas.

Comment: Thanks u for your quick answer. I have tested the three methods which you suggested. At first al the three methods did not compile. I decided to create a small wrapper class for int and voila, the program runs correctly for the first case(mapFunction and ReduceFunction outside the class). As for the other methods, I'm not so lucky. I will edit my post with the working program

Comment: @Mafura By just adding `static` in front of `mappedFunction` and `reduce` in your original code, the program compile. You probably made a mistake elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging and rereading the [Qtconcurrency on using member functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentmap.html#using-member-functions)
I realised that there are 2 major points

1. The class of the container and the member functions  SHOULD be the same
2. In order to avoid head aches with passing this parameter, make the member functions static

Here is the final working version

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <functional>

class intObj{
    int m_value;
public:
    intObj(int val = 0):m_value(val){}

    int val() const {return m_value;}

    static intObj mapFunction(const intObj &num){
        return intObj(num.val());
    }

    static void reduceFunction(intObj &sum, const intObj &term){
        int x = sum.val();
        int y = term.val();
        sum = intObj(x+y);
    }

};

class myTest{
    public:
    int getSum(QList<intObj> numbers);

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QList<intObj> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++){
        n.append(intObj(i));
    }

    myTest m;
    int sum = m.getSum(n);
    return a.exec();
}


int myTest::getSum(QList<intObj> numbers){
    auto sum = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(numbers,&intObj::mapFunction,&intObj::reduceFunction);
    return sum.result().val();
}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this program are most welcome.

Comment: You misunderstood the documentation - You don't need both a wrapper object and static method. Either you use static method (as shown in my answer), or you use a member-method on wrapper object (typical example is `.length()` on `QString()`).